# National Student ClearingHouse SOAP web service implementation

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap-client

I'm working on a project where there's a requirement to verify registered members with National Student ClearingHouse using their API. I've been looking everywhere on the internet to find some snippet which describes the method or example how to query this, But no luck so far. Documentation is also very limited to implement in php plus I've never worked on SOAP so that makes this even more complicated for me.

**Link to Documentation:**
https://docs.google.com/file/d/1kZvEeobFNq3kbhZKJnagkVhcWhKHHwL5dwckbJLTB4dhNpMSF7cjAVOp9cne/edit?usp=sharing

Somehow I've manage to get started here is the code:

```
$soap_url = 'https://xml.studentclearinghouse.org/ws/wsdl/HRXMLVerify.wsdl';

$client = new SoapClient($soap_url, array(
            'SOAP-ENV' => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
            'SOAPENC'  => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/',
            'xsi'      => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance',
            'xsd'      => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
    ));

$data = array(
        'BackgroundCheck' => array(
                'account' => 'xxxx',
                'userid'  => 'xxxxx',
                'password' =>  'xxxxx'
            ),

        'BackgroundSearchPackage' => array()

    );
echo '<pre>';
print_r($client->__soapCall('verifyHRXML', $data));
```

**Which outputs:**

```
   SoapFault Object
(
    [message:protected] => SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'BackgroundSearchPackage' property
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nch/index.php
    [line:protected] => 39
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/nch/index.php
                    [line] => 39
                    [function] => __soapCall
                    [class] => SoapClient
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => verifyHRXML
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [BackgroundCheck] => Array
                                        (
                                            [account] => xxxxxx
                                            [userid] => xxxxx
                                            [password] => xxxxxx
                                        )

                                    [BackgroundSearchPackage] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
    [faultstring] => SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'BackgroundSearchPackage' property
    [faultcode] => Client
    [faultcodens] => http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
)
```

Stuck wit this very badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is stated as: "object has no 'BackgroundSearchPackage' property", basically your soap call is not obeying the requirements from the wsdl. I'll paste these below. This particular call expects BOTH node content and attributes. See the first comment in the php documentation here to see how that's done: http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

So with that said, you could try making your call with your data as:

```
$data = array(
    'BackgroundCheck' => array(
            '_' => array(
                'BackgroundSearchPackage' => array()
                ),
            'account' => 'xxxx',
            'userid'  => 'xxxxx',
            'password' =>  'xxxxx'
        )
);
```

Note: With soap, all available operations and descriptions of their inputs, and return values are described in the wsdl. You provided the url: https://xml.studentclearinghouse.org/ws/wsdl/HRXMLVerify.wsdl . I am pasting below the relevant pieces of information for your case:

```
<message name="HRXMLVerifySoapIn">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:BackgroundCheck"/>
</message>
<message name="HRXMLVerifySoapOut">
    <part name="parameters" element="s0:BackgroundReports"/>
</message>
<portType name="HRXMLVerifySoapPort">
    <operation name="verifyHRXML">
        <documentation>Display the detail results of verification.</documentation>
        <input message="intf:HRXMLVerifySoapIn"/>
        <output message="intf:HRXMLVerifySoapOut"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
```

Description of BackgroundCheck

```
<xsd:element name="BackgroundCheck" type="BackgroundCheckType" >
    <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>Parent Element for  specifying Search Subject specfic data for Standalone Searches.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
```

Description of BackgroundCheckType (refer to line 3195 of wsdl). BackgroundCheckType *contains* an element "BackgroundSearchPackage".

```
<xsd:complexType name="BackgroundCheckType" >
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="ReferenceId" type="EntityIdType" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Reference Number associated with all searches within the XML Document.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="BackgroundSearchPackage" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Root element containing all screening related information for a single Search Subject.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="ReferenceId" type="EntityIdType" minOccurs="0">
                            <xsd:annotation>
                                <xsd:documentation>Reference Number associated with all searches within the specified package.</xsd:documentation>
                            </xsd:annotation>
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="ClientContact" type="ReferralType" minOccurs="0">
                            <xsd:annotation>
                                <xsd:documentation>Contact point within clients organization regarding details of screening package.<   /xsd:documentation> 
                            </xsd:annotation>
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="Organization" type="ReferralType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xsd:annotation>
                                <xsd:documentation>Identifies the organization that  the search(s) will be performed upon or on behalf of depending on the value of type.</xsd:documentation>
                            </xsd:annotation>
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="PersonalData" type="ScreeningPersonalDataType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xsd:annotation>
                                <xsd:documentation>Personal data related to the Search Subject that the search(s) will be performed upon.</xsd:documentation>
                            </xsd:annotation>
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="Screenings" type="ScreeningRequestType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" use="optional"></xsd:attribute>
                <xsd:attribute name="action" type="xsd:string" use="optional"></xsd:attribute>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element ref="UserArea" minOccurs="0"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="userId" type="xsd:string" use="required">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Client identification.  This will be provided to the client by the organization performing the screenings.</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="password" type="xsd:string" use="optional"></xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="account" type="xsd:string" use="optional"></xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="location" type="xsd:string" use="optional"></xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="version" type="xsd:string" use="optional" default="2_0"></xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute ref="xml:lang" use="optional"></xsd:attribute>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: have to send `BackgroundSearchPackage` with an array filled with the data of member for which I'm requesting the verification. That's why it is mandatory.

Comment: Right, well, you need to obey the requirements from the wsdl, and there is no "BackgroundSearchPackage" as the same level as "BackgroundCheck". But you are right, I answerwed too quickly without checking the wsdl in details. "BackgroundSearchPackage" is defined *in* "BackgroundCheck", and all of the other input (e.g. userid) are attributes. I've amended my answer and added some reference links and snippets from the wsdl.

Comment: argh, saved the answer too quickly, edited one last time, I hope it works! And one last note: when you have nested complex types like these, you should consider class mapping, see the classmap parameter for the SoapClient constructor: http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

Comment: Thanks for the description I'll try to implement this. Also, Can you share some example php code which I can lookup to? For SOAP classmap